# Modularizing python code

Tags: python

I have around 2000 lines of code in a python script. I decided to cleanup the code and moved all the helpers in a helpers.py file and all the configs and imports in a config.py file 
Here my main file:

```
from config import *
from helpers import *
from modules import *
```

And in my config file I've writted

```
import threading as th
```

And then in modules I am extending a thread class

```
class A(th.Thread):
...
```

I get an error that th is not defined.And when I import config in my modules class, it works fine. I don't have a clear picture on how imports work here.
Also, is there any best practice to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's `from module import *` isn't the same as require/include that you may see in other languages like PHP.

The star import works by executing/loading the module first, then merging the module's namespace to the current namespace. This means that `module` have to import its own dependencies itself. You can do that by adding `from config import *` in `module`, or better to do `import threading as th` in `module` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Read `import threading as th` as `th = __import__("threading")`: it's an assignment first and foremost. Thus, you have to do the import in *every* file where you're using the variable.

PS: `import *` is best avoided.